# how to mention a target blank in grid view. how to add target blank in action page

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

How to mention a target `_blank` in symfony action page?

```
$myRowAction = new RowAction('View', 'viewinvoice');
$grid->addRowAction($myRowAction);
```

If i click a (view) in grid page, the data display in new window.

Comment: shanthi, you will have to give a lot more context. What are you trying to achieve? What bundles are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Seem you are using the [APY/APYDataGridBundle](https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle). Reading the doc here specify how to define the target of your link: is the 4th parameters of the constructor. As Example:

```
$myRowAction = new RowAction('View', 'viewinvoice', false, '_blank'); 
$grid->addRowAction($myRowAction);
```

Hope this help

For the future, please mention which library/framework are you using and what you tried. Take care to use the correct tag also (this issue is not about sf1.4)

Comment: As usual, Matteo always provides an excellent answer. Thanks for that Matteo. shanthi: Here is a link on how to use the [Add a Row action](https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/grid_configuration/add_row_action.md) properly showing all the parameters.

Comment: thanks @AlvinBunk also for the doc link. I missed in the answer